# Can I respec my skills and attributes?

Tags: grim-dawn

Am I able to respec my skills and attributes in Grim Dawn? Since I don't see the option in any character panels, where can I go to respec?

I started playing but haven't seen anything about respecs about an hour into the game. If it's anything like Titan Quest (see [this thread](http://www.grimdawn.com/forums/showthread.php?t=396)) then I know you can at least respec skills at the cost of resources, but I am curious if they changed the system for Grim Dawn.

Answer (score 11):

Updated answer for the Ashes of Malmouth (11 Oct 2017) DLC:

**Character Attributes**
Can be respecced with a [Tonic of Reshaping](https://www.grimtools.com/db/items/8917). You get one of this as a reward from the very first side quest in the expansion. Alternatively, you can also farm it as an epic drop from Nemesis bosses.

**Devotion Points**
You can reset Devotion Points with a Spirit Guide. Alternatively, you can also farm the [Tonic of Clarity](https://www.grimtools.com/db/items/2906) as an epic drop from Nemesis bosses.

**Skill Points**
You can reset both skill and mastery points with a Spirit Guide. The cost rises after every 20 points you reset, as follows:

```
+---------+-------+
| Points  | Cost  |
+---------+-------+
| 01-20   |    25 |
| 21-40   |    50 |
| 41-60   |   100 |
| 61-80   |   150 |
| 81-100  |   200 |
| 101-120 |   300 |
| 121-140 |   400 |
| 141-160 |   500 |
| 161-180 |   750 |
| 181-200 |  1000 |
| 201-220 |  1250 |
| 221-240 |  1500 |
| 241-260 |  2000 |
| 261-280 |  2500 |
| 281-300 |  3000 |
| 301-320 |  4000 |
| 321-340 |  5000 |
| 341-360 |  7500 |
| 361-380 | 10000 |
| 381+    | 15000 |
+---------+-------+
```

Answer (score 9):

We have to differentiate between different things here, when we talk about respec.

**Character Attributes**

Those cannot be respecced at all.

**Skills**

You can remove single skills by talking to the so called "Spirit Guide" in the game which can be found in the northern corner of Devil's Crossing . After each skill point being removed, the cost for it rises significantly.

**Devotion**

Single Devotion points can be reset by talking to the Spirit Guide in Devil's Crossing. However, they cannot be removed if a constellation grants affinity and those have points invested.

To completely reset all your devotion points at once, you need to find a Tonic of Clarity, which can drop from Nemesis bosses in Grim Dawn.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can respec  (Note that this answer is based on to the current state of the Alpha (currently build 13 as I write this).

Once you get access to the first town, upstairs in one of the cells is a "spirit guide", who will allow you to remove previously allocated skill points (so you can reallocate them differently).

I haven't used this facility, but it says you pay for it (but I can't tell you if it's in iron bits or in experience points - I'm betting the former).